# Sailsjs Policies with async functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, sails.js

What I try to do, is to implement express-brute to a sailsjs application as policy.

Therefore I registered a policy bruteForce.

My bruteForce.js file contains:

```
const ExpressBrute = require('express-brute'),
  moment = require('moment'),
  SequelizeStore = require('express-brute-sequelize'),
  Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const failCallback = (req, res, next, nextValidRequestDate) =>  {
  res.status(429).json({
    message: 'You\'ve made too many failed attempts in a short period of time, please try again '+moment(nextValidRequestDate).fromNow(),
    nextValidRequestDate,
    tryAgainIn: moment(nextValidRequestDate).diff(moment)
  })
}

const handleStoreError = (error) => {
  sails.log.error(error);
  throw {
    message: error.message,
    parent: error.parent
  };
}

const store = new ExpressBrute.MemoryStore();

const bruteForceOptions = {
  freeRetries: 3,
  minWait: 1000*60,
  maxWait: 1000*60*15,
  failCallback,
  handleStoreError
}

const bruteforce = new ExpressBrute(store, bruteForceOptions)

module.exports = async function (req, res, next) {
  return bruteforce.prevent(req, res, next)
};
```

That is working so far, but when I try to set another store driver - I chose now the Sequelize driver.

Therefore I added:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('table', 'root', 'secret', {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  dialect: 'mysql',
  operatorsAliases: false,
  logging: sails.log.debug
});

const getBruteforce = async function(){
  new SequelizeStore(sequelize, 'bruteStore', {}, function(store) {
    console.log(store)
    return new ExpressBrute(store, bruteForceOptions)
  });
}
```

and my new policy function is:

```
module.exports = async function (req, res, next) {
  const bruteforce = await getBruteforce()
  return bruteforce.prevent(req, res, next)
};
```

But here I always get the error bruteforce undefined and the console.log in the callback of new SequelizeStore is called afterward.

I don't understand how I could fix that.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1):

Because your `getBruteforce()` function doesn't actually return anything.

```
const getBruteforce = async function(){
  new SequelizeStore(sequelize, 'bruteStore', {}, function(store) {
    console.log(store)
    // Below returns from the callback, **not** the async function
    return new ExpressBrute(store, bruteForceOptions)
  });
}
```

Do this instead:

```
const getBruteforce = function(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    new SequelizeStore(sequelize, 'bruteStore', {}, function(store) {
      console.log(store)
      // Fulfill the returned promise
      resolve(new ExpressBrute(store, bruteForceOptions))
    });
  });
}
```

I'd recommend you read up on how to [return values from async functions](https://thecodebarbarian.com/80-20-guide-to-async-await-in-node.js.html#return-values-and-exceptions).